# Weird behavior with SELECT and the <= and >= operators, returns junk or none

Tags: dictionary, rebol

I'm trying to make a map of operators to their opposites in Rebol 2, for instance:

```
op-map: [
    >= [<]
    <= [>]
]
```

This does not work for `<=`:

```
>> select op-map to-word "<="
== none  ;-- expected [>]
```

And gives a very strange response for `>=`:

```
>> select op-map to-word ">="
== [<]
    <= [>]  ;-- expected just [<]
```

This works correctly in Rebol 3.  Is it a bug?  How to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a bug in the Rebol 2 parsing logic.  It sees the first `<` and then begins interpreting the subsequent input as if it were a TAG! type *(as in, HTML tag)* until it finds a closing `>`.  Note this:

```
>> length? op-map
== 2

>> op-map/2/1
== <]
    <= [>

>> type? op-map/2/1
== tag!
```

So to Rebol's 2 mind, it's akin to if you had written something more along the lines of:

```
op-map: [
    >= [<a href="http://hostilefork.com">]
]
```

And it's not just BLOCK! that has this problem, it happens with PAREN! too:

```
>> op-map: first [(>= (<) <= (>))]
== (>= (<) <= (>))

>> length? op-map
== 2
```

I'm not entirely sure what the rules are that are making this work in Rebol 3.  It doesn't disallow brackets inside of tags:

```
>> print <[o]>
== <[o]>
```

...but you can't use unmatched closing braces in source, while opening ones are tolerated:

```
>> print <]>
** Syntax error: missing "[" at "end-of-block"
** Near: (line 1) print <]>

>> print <[>
<[>
```

...but you can use unmatched closing ones when they are inside of quotes:

```
>> print <"]">
<"]">
```

Stranger still, you can create a tag containing only an unmatched closed brace programmatically:

```
>> print to-tag "]"
<]>
```

So while it looks to have better behavior in the kind of case given, it's hard to tell if there was ever really a formalized logic in terms of a "fix".  The new rules may have a similar but more subtle class of problem.  In the meantime, to be on the safe side, when dealing with these operators in Rebol 2 you can try creating them from strings:

```
op-map: compose/deep [
    (to-word ">=") [(to-word "<")]
    (to-word "<=") [(to-word ">")]
]
```

It's more verbose.  But the presence of the string delimiters will prevent the parser from trying to interpret the `<` and `>` as tag delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Add spaces—using `<` and `>` in words are special cases due to the dual use in tags (as you suggest). As with regular use e.g. `3 < 4`, putting a space after `<` will prevent the parser from confusing it with a tag and treat as a word:

```
op-map: [
    >= [< ]
    <= [>]
]
```

Comment: Hmmm... okay, but that's not very self-documenting.  Definitely looks like something that someone would go in and just delete if you didn't leave a stern comment.  :-(  Hopefully this will get straightened out in a more uniform way!

Comment: Well, as you suggest—it works correctly in R3, so has been straightened out to the extent that it will be. Unless there's a 2.7.9...